# Extract Table information from .docx in the form of dictionary and dataframe using python

Tags: python, dictionary, datatable, ms-word, python-docx

I am trying to read a word document and extract all table information in the form of json or dataframe with key and value.

Sample image of tables in word document is as below.

[image]

Expected Output:

**[image: strong text]**

Below is the code I tried out but the mapping is not done properly.

```
big_data = []

for table in document.tables:

data = []

keys = None
for i, column in enumerate(table.columns):
    text = (cell.text for cell in column.cells)

    if i == 0:
        keys = tuple(text)
        continue
    row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
    data.append(row_data)
    

    #print (data)
    big_data.append(data)
```

Output received on the above command is huge and just pasting a small sample of the output here.

[image]
Could please help me in achieving the expected output.

Comment: What did you get from your code?  Show us.  You haven't told us what's wrong.  Also please note that not every table has a header row.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, Thanks for the message, I have added a screenshot of sample output and the output dictionary is big that it loops for each item in the table.

Comment: You can see the problem here, right?  Your code is assuming that column 0 is the key, and all the other columns have data.  When you have 4 columns, that's not true.  There is a new header.  However, I believe the fix is easy.  Instead of `if i == 0:`, use `if i % 2 == 0:`.  That will assume that the even columns are keys, and odd columns are data.

Comment: Thanks for the above idea @TimRoberts, if i % 2 == 0: logic seems to work fine only for the first column, for column 2 in table 1, its not able to map right,  The results are something like 'Next Due Date ': 'Next Due Date ', Logistics_com':'Logistics_com'

Comment: Without having your document, we can't debug this.  Word documents are not always organized in a straightforward manner.  You will have to do debug prints to find out what you're getting at each step, in order to extract yourdata.